# Negative ID's value and INSERT

Tags: java, hibernate

I have an Id field annotated with `@GeneratedValue`.
Is there any way to make hibernate autoincrement value that field if I pass negative value and not only zero?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I found the solution: its called [hibernate iterceptor](https://sites.google.com/a/pintailconsultingllc.com/java/Home/hibernate-interceptor-for-new-entities)

Answer (score 1):

You can also avoid the negative ID's using allocationSize:

```
@Id
@SequenceGenerator(name = "Template_SEQ", allocationSize=1)
@GeneratedValue(strategy = GenerationType.SEQUENCE, generator = "Template_SEQ")
```

I've tested with Hibernate 4.3.1.